# finite set of fractional diophantine equations

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations

Suppose I am given a finite set of rational numbers and I am told that these are fractions of the form 
$(an^2+bn+c)/(dn+e)$ for fixed integers $a,b,c,d,e$ and varying integer $n$. I am not told what $a,b,c,d,e$ and the different $n$ are. How am I supposed to find $a,b,c,d,e$ if I have sufficiently large and general amount of numbers in my set. This is not relevant to me, but out of curiosity, what is the minimum cardinality I need for this (general) set to be able to uniquely determine $a,b,c,d$ and $e$.

I was thinking of taking the least common multiple of the difference of the denominators of the fractions to get $e$, but I am not guaranteed that the denominators I get are exactly $dn+e$ (they could be a factor of it, since the numerator and denominator of $(an^2+bn+c)/(dn+e)$ need not be coprime.

Comment: If $f(x) = (a x^2 + b x +c)/(d x + e)$ you will never be able to distinguish $f(x)$ and $f(x + k)$ for an integer $k$. Similarly, if the varying integers $n$ are all divisible by $m$ you won't be able to distinguish $f(x)$ and $f(kx)$ for $k|m$.

Comment: I don't quite follow why. But in any case, that is why I meant the set is sufficiently "general". Meaning that I am avoiding these "singular" cases for which I cannot find the coefficients.

Comment: To make it simpler: Even if you knew that $a=0$, $d=0$, $e=1$, $b=1$ so your "fraction" was $n + c$, you obviously can't determine $c$ from your data.

Comment: +1 I will accept this as an answer, if you make it. Thanks.